# accidentaly got to Gnu Grub prompt. How do I go back?

Tags: grub2, grubrescue, gnu

I'm new on a system 76 preloaded with ubuntu, laptop. I was trying to minimize my screen and was trying a couple options. when I tried ctr+alt+F10 the screen went black with some kind of writing. It says `GNU GRUB version...` it looks like a teminal with a command line only it starts with `grub>` anyone know how I can go back?

Comment: "exit" to reboot but if you did not end up there by accident (pressing a `e` by mistake) you got bigger problems. " I was trying to minimize my screen and was trying a couple options" is not enough to go on. Generic answer: use a live dvd, restore the edits you made and reboot.

Comment: I did that, now it says `reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key` tried rebooting it, didn't help.

Comment: @Rinzwind what should i do now?

Comment: I tried this: https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux and I got to (initramfs). I need help to get out of here.

Comment: Have you tried Cntrl+Alt+F7 yet?